# UTF-8 to Latin(ISO-8859-1) Conversion in C++

Tags: visual-c++, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I would like to know how to write code that performs a UTF-8 to Latin(ISO-8859-1) Conversion in C++.

The following website does the conversion required:
http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/utf8-to-latin-converter.php

Inserting value: Ãºsername

provides the result: úsername

I've got a piece of code that does a similar job from a previous post but doesn't seem to convert the string

```
int utf8_to_unicode(std::deque<int> &coded)
{
    int charcode = 0;
    int t = coded.front();
    coded.pop_front();
    if (t < 128)
    {
        return t;
    }
    int high_bit_mask = (1 << 6) -1;
    int high_bit_shift = 0;
    int total_bits = 0;
    const int other_bits = 6;
    while((t & 0xC0) == 0xC0)
    {
        t <<= 1;
        t &= 0xff;
        total_bits += 6;
        high_bit_mask >>= 1; 
        high_bit_shift++;
        charcode <<= other_bits;
        charcode |= coded.front() & ((1 << other_bits)-1);
        coded.pop_front();
    } 
    charcode |= ((t >> high_bit_shift) & high_bit_mask) << total_bits;
    return charcode;
}
```

Help please!

Comment: [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) could be useful.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm looking for a solution which hard codes this conversion within the source code

Comment: Iconv is also a library [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/). I'm not sure to understand what you mean to hard code the conversion in the source code. Can't you configure your text editor used for your source code (e.g. `emacs`) to save it in the wanted encoding?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch please see the above code for what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

You need the [iconv(3)](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv.3.html) function from `libiconv`. The first argument (some `iconv_t`) to the `iconv` conversion function should be obtained by [iconv_open(3)](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv_open.3.html) at program initialization, probably with

```
 ic = iconv_open("ISO-8859-1","UTF-8");
```

(where `ic` is some static or global `iconv_t` variable).